# WPF ListView object is sometimes recognized by UIAutomation as DataGrid instead of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid, microsoft-ui-automation

We have a `ListView` object that is used in our application, it's a new class `SortableListView : ListView` and using the `GridView` pattern. We have added a custom provider which allows for de-virtualization of rows during automation (so we don't ahve to do the "check on screen, no, scroll, repeat" method of selecting items in the list). It works great and when you realize an off-screen object it is efficiently brought on-screen. We are using ListView because the grids are read-only, so we don't need the edit templates of the DataGrid.

However, sometimes (and we cannot track down exactly what causes it) the ControlType is recognized as a DataGrid rather than ListView. This breaks our automation, and the only way we canf ind around it to, every time we must address the grid, we have to check whether it's presenting itself as a DataGrid or ListView. What's even more disconcerting is the actual rows of the table have Class `ListViewItem`, the exact object form Microsoft unmodified, but are recognized as DataGrid rows instead.

Does anyone know why UIAutomation would decide it's a `DataGrid` instead of a ListView? It's lierally just inherited directly from ListView.

Comment: [Controls have the choice of which patterns they present](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746719(v=vs.110).aspx), and the set of patterns can vary at runtime.

So the question should be, why does ListView choose to present itself as DataGrid?   Alternatively, why does your provider choose to present as DataGrid?

Comment: No, the question is the one I posited. If the answer is "because that's what the control is telling it to do", then I need to know how to stop it from telling the UIAutomation to use that pattern. Your smug non-answer is helping nobody.

Comment: Actually, it *is* an answer.  **Controls may choose to present different patterns at different times.**  You may well have to decide at runtime based on the patterns provided.